# Can I debug/deploy my app on Window RT tablet through USB?

Tags: debugging, usb, windows-runtime

I know I can remote debug my winRT app through wifi, but is it possible to debug/deploy app via USB? I'm asking this, since USB would be faster than the wifi alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via a USB to USB (Easy transfer cable). The cables just simulate a network connection, so it will work like wifi.

You will need to ensure the drivers are compatible with the arm device, but they should be. [This device is made by Microsoft](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/ThemeID.27509700/Easy-Transfer-Cable-for-Windows-8/productID.256540700) for windows 8 so should work: